# Can we configure MATLAB let variable have minium local scope?

Tags: matlab, scope

Can we configure MATLAB let variable have minium local scope?

I want matlab something similiar like C below.

```
% after some configure ...

for i=1:1:100
    a=i*i
end
% here we can not using 'a' any more for it have local scope in for loop.
```

Why I want it becase the scope in whole script sometimes leds to bug hard to find.

For example:

```
% get accumulate of b via 100 times of x_0
b=0;
for i=1:1:100
   x0=100
   b=b+x0
end

% get accumulate of a via 100 times of x_0
a=0
for i=1:1:100
   x_0=200
   a=a+x0    %mistype x_0 to x0, and hard to find
end
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: Not really a solution to this question, but one way to address your issue is to develop a habit of clearing "throwaway" variables once they have been used. I do this often. That is, include a `clear a i` statement after your first loop

Comment: The solution is using functions, as in the answer below, and to use more meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to force a local scope in a script/loop. However, you can create a function, in a separate file or [in the same file](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html). Each function will have it's own local scope. So for your example you can create a file `myScript.m` with the following:

```
% get accumulate of b via 100 times of x_0
accum_b(100)

% get accumulate of a via 100 times of x_0
accum_a(200)

function a = accum_a(x0) 
    a = 0;
    for k = 1:100
        a = a + x0;
    end
end

function b = accum_b(x0) 
    b = 0;
    for k = 1:100
        b = b + x0;
    end
end
```

In this particular example, you can of course call the `accum_a` function twice, with different `x0` inputs. But each function you define in a file will have it's own local scope, and will thus result in an error when mistyping `x_0/x0`.

Comment: "I don't think there is any way..." You're correct. The only variable scopes ("workspaces") in Matlab are base, global, and per-function-call ("stack frame"). There's no block scope or other smaller scope.